# Unity3d Character rotation direction

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Im using the character controller velocity to assign the traform.forward direction

```
function FaceMovementDirection()
{   
    var horizontalVelocity : Vector3 = character.velocity;
    horizontalVelocity.y = 0; // Ignore vertical movement

    // If moving significantly in a new direction, point that character in that direction
    if (horizontalVelocity.magnitude > 0.1)
        thisTransform.forward = horizontalVelocity.normalized;
}
```

my issue is the when the character hits an obstacle , velocity for that axis is 0 and it turns to the side.
i want to keep moving and facing towards the obstacle even if its position is not changing

Any solutions ideas how to do that?

Comment: You've defined your own problem here: your existing code is turning the character to face its direction of movement, but actually you don't *want* the character to face the direction of movement. Your assumed requirements are incorrect - so if you can accurately define the behaviour that you want, you'll be on your way to writing code that meets that requirement.

Comment: Your comment actually gave me the answer. instead of using velocity i used the joystick input to rotate.

Thanks for the help!